# How to delete a TableRow in WordProcessingML using OOXML?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a super simple document with just a table with a few blank rows and I'm trying to remove all the rows. ( The purpose is to actually remove just the blank rows ultimately but I wasn't having any luck with removing any rows at all).

```
public static void SearchAndReplace(string document)
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
            {
               var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                foreach (var table in body.Elements<Table>())
                {
                    foreach (var row in table.Elements<TableRow>())
                    {
                        table.RemoveChild<TableRow>(row);
                        continue;

                    }
                }             
                doc.Save();
            }
        }
```

The document has a single page, with just one table with four rows but the above doesn't remove any rows for some reason.

I've also tried

```
row.Remove()
```

This has no effect either, i.e. after running this no row gets removed. Any ideas what is wrong with this? This is what my document looks like

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Open the document in Word, delete a row, save to a new name and close. Open the original in the Open XML SDK then use its Compare feature to open the second document. That will generate the code required to create the second from the first.

Comment: just discovered that using "Elements<TableRow>().ToList()" fixes the issue and the rows get deleted as expected. Would be nice to know why this works if someone could shed some light.

Comment: @LePrinceDeDhump, my answer below explains why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first attempt, you used the `IEnumerable<TableRow>` created by the `OpenXmlElement.Elements<T>()` method, which enumerates `TableRow` instances from the collection of `ChildElements` of your `Table`. That collection of `ChildElements` is computed dynamically and instances are returned using `yield return`. This happens while you change that collection of `ChildElements` by removing elements,

1. which means you are breaking the links between children and their parents and siblings,
2. which means you don't get the full set of `TableRow` elements,
3. which means you can't delete the `TableRow` instances.

However, I'd guess you should be able to delete the first `TableRow` instance.

Using `ToList()`, you materialize the collection of `TableRow` instances and get hold of all of them in a separate `List<TableRow>`. This way, you are working on a fixed collection rather than one that is computed dynamically as you go. And this is why this works.

As a general rule, you should never change a collection (e.g., by deleting elements of the collection) that you enumerate.